# Ajax call after form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit

I have the following problem with an ajax call after a form is submitted.

```
$('#EVE_fileupload').on('submit', function() 
{
    var apcID = $('#APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS').val(); 

    GetUploadProgress(apcID);
    return true;
});
```

In this case the Ajax call in the GetUploadProgress function always returns an error.
I guess this is due to the submit event in the browser. When i "return false" in the submit function, the ajax call is ok and i get the right response message.

Anyone a hint for me ?

Comment: Once a form is submitted the page reloads, and all is lost !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prevent page refresh after the form is submited. That's why your form is working when you are returning false.

```
$('#EVE_fileupload').on('submit', function(e) 
{

    e.preventDefault();

    var apcID = $('#APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS').val(); 

    GetUploadProgress(apcID);

});
```